extracting metadata from image files (IPTC) in a Flask app - problems solved - clean py file
I’m stuck with a tricky issue with image files (at PAW : PythonAnywhere).
While coding for extracting metadata from image files, I’m succeeding with some of them, while others are claimed to not exist, or not to be a file.
However all jpg files are equivalent for processing by my code:

All are in the same folder , and I have no path problem with them
All are jpg, jpeg files ; some of them with manually added metadata (via ACDSEE tool on windows): but these particular files are being processed correctly

import os, os.path
import iptcinfo3

from pathlib import Path

for fname in os.listdir('static/ImagesCabWillA'):
    fil1=Path(fname)
    if not fil1.exists():
        print(fname, " doesn't exist")
print("§"*15)

for fname in os.listdir('static/ImagesCabWillA'):
    if os.path.isfile(fname):
        print('ok ', fname, 'type : ', type(fname))
    else:
        print('NOT ok : ',fname, 'type : ', type(fname))

print('==== end list1 ====')

for fname in os.listdir('static/ImagesCabWillA'):
    if os.path.isfile(fname) and fname.split(".")[1] in ("jpg","jpeg","JPG","JPEG"):
        print("\n",fname,"\n")
        info = iptcinfo3.IPTCInfo(fname, force=True)
        print('-----------')
        print(info)
        # python what is b prefix in string printing : byte, byte string
        print (type(info["headline"]))
        print('=============')      #       <class 'bytes'>
#        if isinstance(info['object name'],bytes):
        print('zzzzzzzzz')
        print(info["headline"].decode("utf-8"))     #       , "\n"
        print(info["object name"].decode("utf-8"), "\n" )

I Investigated quite a lot on Google, but I don’t get the clue :

There is nothing specific to Flask in this problematic code; it is plain and simple Python …
I tried with os.path.isfile(), and with pathlib.Path(), but the problem is the same….
I’m suspecting heterogeneity in the encoding of various jpg filenames or internal coding of jpg files (some came initially via Whatsapp, while others from the phone or from a camera…)
I’m suspecting that file-object class is modified by the "for loop" processing ...

Any idea will be most welcome
My current code, focusing on debugging this issue:
test_iptc3.py
folder content :
01.jpg  2024-03-22 20:33    45.3 KB
02_DSCF0225.JPG 2024-03-22 20:33    525.5 KB
03_IMG-20220517-WA0006.jpeg 2024-03-22 20:33    317.7 KB 04_IMG_20220207_182856.jpg 2024-03-22 20:33    386.8 KB
05_IMG-20220325-WA0014.jpeg 2024-03-22 20:33    201.5 KB
06_IMG-20220517-WA0013.jpeg 2024-03-22 20:33    303.9 KB
07_IMG-20220325-WA0021.jpeg 2024-03-22 20:33    197.9 KB
08_IMG_20220509_193214.jpg  2024-03-22 20:33    430.4 KB
09_DSCF8528.JPG 2024-03-22 20:33    273.1 KB
DSCF9384Lite.JPG    2024-04-14 17:42    462.2 KB
DSCF9387Lite.JPG    2024-04-14 16:33    496.4 KB
Python console output:

os.listdir() returns bare names, not full paths; If os.path.isfile(x) or Path(x).exists() for an x returned by os.listdir(somewhere) where somewhere isn't the current working directory, returns True, it means there's a file or directory by that name x in your process's working directory, by chance. To wit:
>>> os.listdir("c:/temp")
['basic']
>>> x = _[0]
'basic'
>>> os.path.exists(x)
False

If you do os.listdir('static/ImagesCabWillA'):, you'd need to os.path.join that path to the names you get to get at the actual path:
>>> os.path.exists(os.path.join("c:/temp", x))
True

IOW, something like
for name in os.listdir('static/ImagesCabWillA'):
    assert os.path.exists(os.path.join('static/ImagesCabWillA', name))

You'll have an easier time using Path.glob() (or Path.iterdir()) though:
for p in pathlib.Path('static/ImagesCabWillA').glob("*.*"):
    print(p)  # will represent a full path

Then, you can do
if p.is_file() and p.suffix.lower() in (".jpg", ".jpeg"):
   # process this likely-a-jpeg file


Really much helping answer! Thanks a lot!

Please don't forget to upvote AKX's useful answer.

Here is final code
# IPTC-Album.py cleaned for StackOverlow
import os, os.path
import iptcinfo3        # for iptc metadata
import logging    # for avoiding IPTC3 numerous warnings about unicode, useless/obsoletes
from pathlib import Path

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True #  False
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'aSecretKey'
# for avoiding IPTC3 numerous warnings
iptcinfo_logger = logging.getLogger('iptcinfo')
iptcinfo_logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

@app.route('/ImagesCabWillA/')
def  ImagesCabWillA():
    CollectionIPTCa=[]
    i=0
    for p in Path('/home/PyDelens/SimpleFlask/mysite/static/ImagesCabWillA').glob("*.*"):
        if p.is_file() and p.suffix.lower() in (".jpg", ".jpeg"):
            CollectionIPTCa.append(["item " + str(i)])
            CollectionIPTCa[i].append(os.path.basename(p))
            info = iptcinfo3.IPTCInfo(p, force=True)
            if isinstance(info['object name'],bytes):
                CollectionIPTCa[i].append(info["object name"].decode("utf-8"))
                CollectionIPTCa[i].append(info["headline"].decode("utf-8"))
                print("CollectionIPTCa : ")
                print(CollectionIPTCa[i])
                print("p"*12)
            else:
                print("info['object name'] is not byte type\n")
                continue
            i+=1
        else:
            print(os.path.basename(p) , "  is not a jpg file\n")
            continue

    return render_template("Album2024a/Album2024b.htm", testarray =  testarray1, collectionIPTC =  CollectionIPTCa, CollectionIPTCmimic =  "CollectionIPTCmimic", myi =  i)

Worthwhile noting these corrections:

import/use  logging lib, for avoiding IPTC3 numerous warnings about unicode, useless/obsoletes
use indeed absolute path ( "/home/ ... /ImagesCabWillA" ), even if relative path seems to be ± working
make sure the IPTC fields you use in your images manager are correctly mapped ("object name", "headline", in my case) ; I love ACDSee as a image bulk tool.
note that in my last line, CollectionIPTCmimic and myi are just test components for checking the Jinja2 processing, separately from IPTC3 gotcha's

IPTC3 seems to me a wonderful resource, at the time of Instagram and smartphones success ....
Yours
